# Laravel 5.3: no cookies are set on browser, getting TokenMismatchException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.3 app on Ubuntu 18.04. Whenever I submit a form I get the following error

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

I checked, my form token is present in the form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="1axYN6BB8nkhoncOrLshJykbAhmlsjoxiDvYYqxI">
```

I checked my cookies, no cookies are being created on client side. In chrome development tool Storage/Cookies, no values present.

So I think the issue is cookies are not set on my browser

My server storage permission is 777 and I can files inside storage/framework/sessions folder.

The same applications work on my localhost (windows)

What could be the reason for no cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem in Laravel 5.3.  It is solved in later versions, but I have several apps that also remain on 5.3 due to breaking changes that we can't update in prod.

There are several reasons why this might be happening.  Here are a few that may help you:

**1)** You didn't say how you got the value on your form.  Make sure the value is supplied by Laravel: ie `value="{{ csrf_token() }}"`

**2)** Check for spaces in your `routes/web.php` file. In this version of Laravel, a space before the opening tag `<?php` caused it to fail.

**3)** You say this was working on one server and not another. If one is using a non-secure connection with `SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE` set to true, this could be the issue.  Try flipping to false and test.

**4)** This was my solution:  In `config/session.php` set `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),` or your site, and then either remove `SESSION_DOMAIN` from the file (.env), or set it to your site.  Then run composer dumpautoload, and clear caches.  I had the wrong session setup.

Hopefully one of these will point you in the right direction.